# Why I got a Int from a string in sqlite3 with flask (python3)?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to get the "username" and "password" data from sqlite3 with flask(use python3.4). The database schema is like this:

```
create table users (
    username string primary key,
    password string not null
);
```

This is my login code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
error = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select username, password from users')
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        if username == row[0] and password == row[1]:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['username'] = username
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
        else:
            print(row[0]=='admin')
            print(row[1]=='123')
            print(row[1]+1)

    error = 'Invalid username or password, '+username+','+password+'.'
return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

I tested it using username="admin" and password="123". Attention that three print code. I'm very surprised when I find the second print return false, and the third one is "124".  I can't understand why "row[1]" turned to be a Integer rather than a String since "password" is a string in the database.

I am a novice in python and flask. I think it is non-reasonable because I didn't do any translation from string to int. I test it again using username="test" and password="test", and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that `string` does not actually appear to be a valid column affinity in sqlite3, and you should be declaring those columns as `TEXT` instead.  From the [sqlite3 datatype documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> And the declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not TEXT.

This then has the following implication (also from the same documentation):

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible.

So when `123` is stored in that column, it is stored as an integer because the conversion was possible.  When `test` is stored there, it gets stored as text only because no reasonable conversion to an integer or real was possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed "string" to "text" and it works.